# systemd throws an error

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, daemon, systemctl

I'm doing VPS hosting via the telegram bot systemd here's the code in the bot.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Roflbaza
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/roflbaza/bot.service
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /roflbaza/bot.py
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

the link symbol was created ([image]2 pcs) after the systemctl start bot command and then the systemctl status bot comes out, this is help, please, a screenshot of the error below[image]

systemctl daemon-reload i wrote